# Better way to add spaces between double semicolons

Tags: c#, string, replace

My task is simple: I have a CSV file inside a C# string, split with semicolons. I need to add spaces for each empty cell. `A;B;;;;C;` should become `A;B; ; ; ;C;`. Right now, I'm using the replace method twice:

```
csv = csv.Replace(";;", "; ;").Replace(";;", "; ;");
```

That's necessary, because in the first pass, it will replace any occurance of ;; with a space between, but there's no lookback, so the second semicolon of the replaced sequence won't be checked again. Therefore I would end up with a `A;B; ;; ;C;`, which is not what I want.

Is there a more elegant, clear, and less redundand way to solve that task?

Comment: Is there a chance that this is a XY problem? Replacing empty string with whitespace, does data processed latre somehow differently?

Comment: The scenario is as follows: I write a "normally" formatted CSV string into a specific file. An external legacy software reads and imports these files. If there are any errors, it will write them into a database. The original CSV line is used as a key. But it doesn't copy the lines exactly, but adds those spaces. So to find the error entry in that database, I have to replicate the modification to my CSV file as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) string into the parts, then replace empty entries with spaces using [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) (it requires `using System.Linq;`) and [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) the entries back

```cs
var str = "A;B;;;;C";
var parts = str.Split(';').Select(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p) ? " " : p);

var result = string.Join(";", parts);
```

The output will be the following `A;B; ; ; ;C`

Benchmark result in comparison with OP code and `Regex` solution:

[image]

What is the clear and more elegant is up to you decision.
Benchmark code for the reference is below

```cs
[SimpleJob]
public class Benchmark
{
    string input= "A;B;;;;C";

    [Benchmark]
    public string SplitJoinTest()
    {
        var parts = input.Split(';').Select(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p) ? " " : p);
        return string.Join(";", parts);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public string DoubleReplaceTest()
    {
        return input.Replace(";;", "; ;").Replace(";;", "; ;");
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public string RegexTest()
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, ";(?=;)", "; ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the double-replace option to your benchmark just for comparison?

Comment: @AndréReichelt np, I've added a details, double replace is the fastest method:)

Answer (score 9):

One way is to use regular expressions.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var result = Regex.Replace("A;B;;;;C;", ";(?=;)", "; ");
```

We replace every semicolon that is followed by another semicolon with the string `"; "`.

It's definitely less redundant, and it's clear if you know how to read regex :) Whether it is more elegant is up to you to decide.